# Deploying multiple maven projects to heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have multiple maven projects as shown in the below structure.

```
    .git

    folder a -> contains main class and with jetty server.

    | 
      main class
    |
      pom.xml

    folder b
    |
     other implementation classes of interface present in folder c
    |
     pom.xml

    folder c
    | 
      Models(Pojo)
    |
      Controller(Rest Controller)
    |
      pom.xml
```

The above 3 folders are added to class path and works perfectly in local envirornment. But when i try to host it in heroku server build fails bcoz of
the following reason.

No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

My pom.xml is inside sub folders and main class is in folder a.

Can i add one more pom.xml in root folder and point that to pom.xml of foldera?
Or how i can host it using executable jar ?

Please help?

Comment: Have you defined a procfile? If so post it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!                                                                                                          web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Svmapp                         here Svmapp is the main class name

Comment: The procfile should be in the root folder and you need to add the subdirectory to the -cp arg e.g. `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp /a/target/classes:target/dependency/*`

Comment: Then there is no need to mention the main class is it?

Comment: Yes, plus the main class I guess.

Comment: web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp /a/target/classes;target/dependency/* com.sample.server Svmapp                                                                                                 i inserted the above line in the Procfile, but still same issue exists. And Procfile is in root folder ,i,e where the .git folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `pom.xml` in the root directory, and then configure it to have the sub-directories as modules. It would look something like this:

```
<modules>
  <module>folder-a</module>
  <module>folder-b</module>
  <module>folder-c</module>
</modules>
```

You may also need to configure the parent pom.xml in the submodules. See [Maven Modules docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) for more info.

Then it depends if you want to build all of those submodules or just one. If you want to build them all, add a `Procfile` to the root directory with a `java` command that points to the `folder-a/target/myapp.jar` or whatever.

If you only want to run one submodule, you'll still need the `Procfile`, but you'll also want to add the `-pl` option to Maven by running:

```
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-pl folder-a"
```

Then the next time you deploy, Heroku will run maven such that only the module in `folder-a` is built.

Answer (score 0):

this error message means that Heroku was unable to automatically detect the type of app you're trying to deploy: Ruby, Node, Python, PHP, Java, etc. It look for signatures for each language that support (like a pom.xml file or package.json file). and it usually means an important file that is package.json isn't checked into your git repository:

You should git add {file}, git commit -am 'added {file}' and then git push heroku master

for more: ref: https://help.heroku.com/1MC2J0GF/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack